# how to save data in csv using node-red

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red

I am using Windows and node-red installation. Getting my data from Modbus-TCP.
Using dash-board able to plot my data as well. Now I want to do data logging along with time stamp as CSV file. Tried to use bigcsv lib but no success.

Thanks

Comment: Show the code or it didn't happen :P

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a library, Node-RED comes with a built in CSV node and the File out node.

[image]

You will probably need to use a function node to add the timestamp to the data before passing the msg object with the data you want in the CSV through this node and then wire that to a file out node.

EDIT:

Actually, as this is tagged with Bluemix there is no File node installed by default, because there is no where sensible to write any files that wouldn't be destroyed as soon as the application is restarted.